# Is there a way to unload dynamic text once its loaded in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm enlisting your help on how to unload text that dynamically loaded through a text file in Actionscript 3.0.

I have managed to load the data to my stage, but I  want that when the user hits the back button to go home, the data vanishes. At the moment, the data is still appearing even when you hit the back button (whose instance is page3home in the code below.)

Below is my code:

```
import flash.display.Loader;

var myTextLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var myTextField_txt:TextField = new TextField();
var myTextUnloader:Loader=new Loader();
var textStyle:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
textStyle.font = "Verdana";
textStyle.size = 14;
myTextField_txt.wordWrap=true;
myTextField_txt.autoSize=TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
myTextField_txt.multiline = true;
myTextField_txt.width = 480; 
myTextField_txt.height = 300; 
myTextField_txt.x = 50; 
myTextField_txt.y = 80;

myTextLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);

function onLoaded(e:Event):void {
myTextField_txt.text = e.target.data;
addChild(myTextField_txt);
     myTextField_txt.setTextFormat(textStyle); 
}

myTextLoader.load(new URLRequest("myText.txt"));

up_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scrollUp);

function scrollUp(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
     myTextField_txt.scrollV--;
}

down_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, scrollDown);

function scrollDown(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
     myTextField_txt.scrollV++;
}


page3home.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_11(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(1);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove a [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) ( the text field in your case ) from its parent [`DisplayObjectContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html), you can use the [`removeChild()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#removeChild()) method :

```
myTextField_txt.parent.removeChild(myTextField_txt);
```

Then to free the associated memory, you can add :

```
myTextField_txt = null;
```

You can also remove all event listeners added to your `URLLoader` object like this :

```
myTextLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,but once i insert the code below it gives me the error Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. Would you know how to solve it?

Comment: @AngelaMithi Could you show how did you used my code inside yours ?

Comment: Hi i discovered what i was doing wrong,i had placed the code above in the wrong place,Your solution worked.Thanks.